# ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Good morning, I have django 4.2 and djangorestframework 3.13.1, if I enable it in installed_aps I get the following error, I don't know if it's because of the django version or some dependency.

Anyone know what might be happening?

Thank you

Enabling it in settings.py is where the error occurs

> Settings.py

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

The djangorestframework installs fine with the dependencies it needs, the installed versions appear in the pip list

> pip list

```
asgiref              3.5.2
Django               4.2.dev20220721050550 /home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django
django-debug-toolbar 3.5.0
djangorestframework  3.13.1
importlib-metadata   4.12.0
Pillow               9.2.0
pip                  22.2.2
psycopg2-binary      2.9.3
pytz                 2022.2.1
setuptools           60.9.3
sqlparse             0.4.2
wheel                0.37.1
zipp                 3.8.1
```

> Error

```
python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/utils.py", line 69, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 129, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/utils.py", line 69, in __getitem__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 129, in get_package_libraries
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.http.multipartparser import parse_header
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_header' from 'django.http.multipartparser' (/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/http/multipartparser.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 89, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/utils.py", line 94, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/utils.py", line 94, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/utils.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.http.multipartparser import parse_header
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_header' from 'django.http.multipartparser' (/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/http/multipartparser.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/observatorio/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/observatorio/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 74, in execute
    options["libraries"] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    super().execute(*args, **options)
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 117, in get_installed_libraries
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 111, in handle
    return {
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 117, in <dictcomp>
    self.run(**options)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in run
    return {
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 106, in get_template_tag_modules
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 680, in run_with_reloader
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 131, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'parse_header' from 'django.http.multipartparser' (/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/http/multipartparser.py)
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 661, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 343, in run
    autoreload_started.send(sender=self)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 176, in send
    return [
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 177, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/autoreload.py", line 43, in watch_for_template_changes
    for directory in get_template_directories():
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/autoreload.py", line 16, in get_template_directories
    for backend in engines.all():
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/utils.py", line 94, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/utils.py", line 94, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/utils.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options["libraries"] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 117, in get_installed_libraries
    return {
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 117, in <dictcomp>
    return {
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 106, in get_template_tag_modules
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 131, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'parse_header' from 'django.http.multipartparser' (/home/legacy/Documentos/proyectos/dtsc/django/django/http/multipartparser.py)
```

Comment: i am getting the same issue while upgrading from 3.2 to 4.2 .....can i know how you fixed the issue

Comment: Hello, when I installed the latest version of django, restframework did not have support for this version, so I installed a version of django 4.1 where it does have support.

requirements
REST framework requires the following:
* Python (3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10)
* Django (2.2, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 4.0, 4.1)